# Handling offset naive object

Tags: python-datetime, pytz

I am trying to find the time until the next day according to IST. I am using pytz. I am not getting why "tomorrow" is offset naive while tomorrow is defined using offset aware constants.

I've tried printing stuff like print tomorrow_date - now , but that gives 0 and i do not know how is that happening.

```py
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from pytz import timezone
ist = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
def get_until_tomorrow():
    now = datetime.now(ist)
    #today = date.today()
    tomorrow_date = now + timedelta(days=1)
    tomorrow = datetime.combine(tomorrow_date,time=time(00,00))
    seconds_left = tomorrow - now
    return seconds_left.seconds
print(get_until_tomorrow())
```

I am getting the error that I cannot subtract an offset naive and an offset aware object. `now` is an offset aware object because i set it so directly, but tomorrow is, according to it, an offset naive variable. How is this possible when i have used only offset aware variables to define `tomorrow`?

Comment: Hi. Was my answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to make it offset aware by using localise. See if this helps.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta, time
from pytz import timezone

ist = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
def get_until_tomorrow():
    now = datetime.now(ist)
    tomorrow_date = now + timedelta(days=1)
    tomorrow = datetime.combine(tomorrow_date,time=time(00,00))
    tomorrow = ist.localize(tomorrow) 
    seconds_left = tomorrow - now
    return seconds_left.seconds
print(get_until_tomorrow())
```